# Tkinter - What is the time item, stored in the event object

Tags: python, tkinter

In Tkinter there is an object called event, usually passed to functions, which are called by buttons (or similar objects) in Tkinter.

```
tkinter.Event
```

This event.object has a bunch of items, like x-position or y-position, and also a time-stamp of sorts.

What does this time-stamp represent?

At the moment I am assuming it is the time-difference from the last Sunday morning in Kathmandu to the current time (in Kathmandu). Why Kathmandu? Because it was telling me ~ 17 hours (and 4 days) since 0 and it's only 17 o'clock in the Kathmandu area (maybe summer time?)

---- Update ----

Maybe time from last Python update?

---- Code ---- Python 3.5

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def callback(event):
    print(event.time)

frame = Canvas(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.create_polygon((50,50),(75,50),(75,75))

frame.tag_bind(1, "<Button-1>", callback)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---- Code ---- Python 2.7 (Not checked)

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def callback(event):
    print event.time

frame = Canvas(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.create_polygon((50,50),(75,50),(75,75))

frame.tag_bind(1, "<Button-1>", callback)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you give us example code?

Comment: Your terminology is a little off. `event` isn't a "subfunction", it's an object passed to a function that is called from an event. Also, what you speak of isn't a timer, it's a timestamp.

Comment: Sorry wrote this on the fly, running between lectures.

Comment: @BryanOakley I read your answer and I appreciate it. If there is no other reaction in the next few days, I will accept it. Would have up-voted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of the `Event` class in tkinter source code only says this:

> time - when the event occurred

I assume this comes from the `%t` substitution provided by the underlying tcl/tk interpreter, which is documented to be the following:

> **%t** The time field from the event. This is the X server timestamp (typically the time since the last server reset) in milliseconds, when the event occurred. Valid for most events.

Of course, windows and OSX don't typically have an X server, in which case the time is probably some platform-specific timestamp.